# How do I configure lynx to recognize ^? as delete/backspace?

Tags: macos, debian, lynx

When I use lynx via sshing to a Debian box from MacOS X (Leopard), it doesn't recognize my default backspace ('^?') as such. I would like to know how to map backspace to '^?' for that particular process.  I haven't been satisfied with these solutions:

1) **Setting Terminal to send ^H on Delete and then using 'stty erase ^H' in my bashrc.** This makes things work for lynx but it breaks emacs; I'm used to hitting M-del to delete a whole word and using ^H breaks this behavior for me.

2) **Recompile lynx to accept ^? as 'erase'.** This isn't worth it to me.

3) **Use a simpler *term* value like vt100.** I use xterm-color because I like colors.

I've read this http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html which was interesting, but configuring inputrc didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised by the behavior you describe: backspace sending `^?` is the default behavior on Debian (so it's supposed to work in all applications by default), and on my Debian (lenny) box, both `^?` and `^h` do backspace in lynx, with `TERM=xterm-color` and either `stty erase '^?'` or `stty erase '^h'`.

Comment: Here's a peek at my stty:

intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jacob's answer didn't work for me. `lynx` for my installation, treats `^?` as `\010` (backspace) instead of `\177` (delete). With Jacob's suggested solution I would still have to change my usage of Terminal.app. Here's a solution that worked for me. Anne Baretta's page regarding backspace and delete was immensely helpful: [Backspace/Delete Config](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html).

一. Install expect if it's not installed already.

二. Create a script to replace lynx (or any other executable) like so:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect

    eval spawn -noecho /usr/bin/lynx

    interact {
    \177        {send "\010"}
    "\033\[3~"  {send "\004"}
    }
```

三. Make the script executable and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your logon script on the debian box, or if you run emacs on that to, write a script called lynx that runs stty ... before running lynx.

Comment: This is sort of the solution that I'm looking for, but how do I call stty in the context of executing lynx without changing stty for the entire session?

I tried putting the stty change in my login (.bash_profile) but it didn't do what I wanted it to do :(

Comment: Actually I tried this and it's not the solution I'm looking for. Terminal.app is set to send ^? and lynx doesn't recognize it. So I have to set both Terminal AND stty erase, but I don't want to do that. Theoretically, I'd like to map ^? to delete in lynx. So I need a way to do that just for lynx.