# Emacs-style backward word delete in Vim through OS X terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, vim

Using vim through terminal in OS X, I don't seem to be able to bind meta-backspace to delete a word.

I'm using xterm-color, delete sends ctrl-h, and I have 'Use option as meta-key' checked. This works well for everything else.

^w does the same thing in vim, but my fingers are trained to use option-backspace (delete key on mac keyboards).

In vim through the terminal, if I type i then ^v then meta-backspace I get nothing. In MacVim, I get , which is correct. So it seems to be a terminal encoding problem. Any help is appreciated, I can't imagine I'm the first to try to do this, although there are enough issues with backspace in terminal that it makes googling difficult.

Comment: OK, here's what I did:  

In Terminal's preferences, under keyboard, check "Use option as meta." Then under Advanced, check "Delete sends Ctrl-H." 

In your .vimrc, add the following: 

imap ^[^? ^W

Comment: Add your own fix as an answer and accept it so others will know how to get it working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with lynx. I don't have `Delete sends Ctrl-H` activated and I can get the option-backspace working fine. You might try switching that first. Otherwise, you might look at what I did to get lynx working the way I wanted it to:

[Configuring lynx](https://superuser.com/questions/165224/how-do-i-configure-lynx-to-recognize-as-delete-backspace/166053#166053)

Answer (score 0):

Since using Option as Alt key keeps you from using all the funky special characters which are available through Option key combos, I have got used to using Esc as my Alt key.

Internally, one of the ways for example `Alt-X` is presented to applications running in the terminal is `Esc` (ASCII 27) followed by `X`. On machines having no Alt key, you can therefore send an Alt combination by typing (not holding) `Esc`, followed by the other key.

See `:h timeout` if your Vim still does not recognize your command.